# Multivariable limit of $\frac{3xy^3}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-y}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

What method do I use to prove that this limit DNE as it goes to (x,y)->(0,0)? I tried polar, but that doesn't help: I get a result that has $r^3$ in the numerator.

Comment: Try taking the limit along different lines. $y=0$, $x=0$, $y=x$.

Comment: Also, limit as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ or somewhere else?

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to put the actual limit. So then if I take it along x=0, I get a limit that DNE, and if I take it along y=0, I get 0. So the limit doesn't exist, right? @AlexisOlson

Comment: @JamiPark along $x=0$, the quotient is $0$

Comment: @NickLiu No, it equals $0$ on $x=0, y<0.$

Answer (score 1):

Your function $f(x,y)=\dfrac{3xy^3}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-y}$ is not actually defined when $x=0, y \ge 0$.

When $x=0, y \lt 0$, you have $f(x,y)=0$.  Similarly when $x \not = 0, y=0$, you have $f(x,y)=0$.

But it might be instructive to find a case where the limit was not $0$ at $(0,0)$.  Try for example $x=y^4, y \gt 0$, which will give $f(y^4,y)\gt 6$ for positive $y$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{y \to 0+}f(y^4,y)=6$.

So you can conclude that $f(x,y)$ does not have a limit at $(0,0)$, as indeed you suspected.